# Npgsql - Specified method is not supported

Tags: debugging, nhibernate, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, npgsql

This might be somehow connected to this other issue I had with FNH.

[Fluent NHibernate cannot load MySql.Data from GAC in debug mode of a test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060850/fluent-nhibernate-cannot-load-mysql-data-from-gac-in-debug-mode-of-a-test)

Generally I got a simple test that runs following code first:

```
FluentConfiguration config = Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Database(
        PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("PostgreSQLConnectionString")))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyMapping>());

s_SessionSource = new SessionSource(config);
```

When I am not running it in Debug (just run tests) it works fine.

When I try to debug i get `NotSupportedException`:
Second line throws that (`new SessionSource` one)

> Specified method is not supported.    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetSchema(String collectionName, String[]
>   restrictions) in
>   C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 970

Why in debug throws exception, but when ran without debug no errors?
I am puzzled with this.. Notice again, when I just run code it works fine, it accesses postgre db no prob.

Notice this is not difference between Release and Debug, its Debug in both cases, but in first case I run debug, but in second I run code without debugging.

EDIT: found this question : http://pgfoundry.org/forum/message.php?msg_id=1003008 appears to be my exact issue, but only occurs in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetSchema throws NotSupportedException when its collectionName argument is unknown. You should perhaps upgrade to the [latest patch](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140) that supports the NHibernate test suite.

The exception must be catched by Fluent, but an attached debugger will stop on it.

Comment: Hmm im trying to find a way to download latest version, google etc, how can I upgrade to latest patch? http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140 this download page shows the last version is pretty old compared on date in link you provide.

Comment: downloaded version from september and it works fine in debugger

Comment: yeah, that fixed it for me also