# What differs when Debug build is ran with debugging and without debugging?

Tags: .net, debugging, clr

I used to believe that if we got a `Debug` build it didn't really matter whether:

1. We ran it.
2. Or we debugged it.

everything would be the same.

However recently I ran into 2 different problems, where its clear that something is different when the code is just run, or when it is debugged, even if version of code is supposedly the same.
(namely [Fluent NHibernate cannot load MySql.Data from GAC in debug mode of a test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060850/fluent-nhibernate-cannot-load-mysql-data-from-gac-in-debug-mode-of-a-test)
and [Npgsql - Specified method is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289061/npgsql-fluent-nhibernate-why-in-debug-throws-exception-but-when-ran-without-de))

I am wondering what is that difference between those two in .NET 4.0? Understanding whats different could probably help me solve the issues I am having because I'll at least know where to look for possible causes of bugs in those different cases. I don't understand it when I run unit tests its all green, but when I try to debug them I get various exceptions thrown..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weapon of choice for assembly resolution problems is [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), it shows you where it looked for an assembly and what configuration is being used to tell the CLR where to find the assembly.

There is a secondary failure mode with the kind of assemblies you are having trouble with.  These dbase providers are often managed wrappers that rely on unmanaged DLLs to get the job done.  Windows must be able to find those DLLs.  That tends to fail if they are not copied to a directory that's on the PATH or copied into the same folder as the main EXE.  Carefully read the deployment instructions for these wrappers.

Comment: this must be pretty close to whats going on, thanks. But could you elaborate what is "secondary failure mode"  and what is "primary? failure mode" (if that exists) I am unsure whether its your way of saying this, or thats some common name to my situation.

Comment: Primary = first likely problem: bad config, the kind that fuslogvw.exe will show you.  Secondary = next likely problem: DLL Hell.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging the timing of the code will be slightly different, more so if you sit inside functions too long.  So if the code is time sensitive, you could run into weird errors.  That's about all I can think of.

Comment: yeah me too currently, I didn't mention that, cause what I am experiencing is clearly not connected to this anyhow, and difference is much bigger (if you follow the questions)

Comment: This is true, but I doubt fluent NHibernate has a ton of time-sensitive code.

Comment: I am not sure both issues are connected to fluent nhb , one appears to be npgsql related mostly.. it means both might be failing for different reasons, cause npgsql has nothing to do with GAC ( I think) and it was the reason mysql was failing

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when the debugger is attached, it can stop when exceptions are thrown that would otherwise be caught.

The options "Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries (Managed only)" and "Enable Just My Code" in Tools/Options/Debugging, and the options in Debug/Exceptions... will determine on what exceptions your debugger will break on when thrown.

Comment: unfortunately that setting is already switched off on my machine, and probably thats the default value cause I don't remember ever setting it.

Comment: Do you have anything checked under Debug/Exceptions... ? And do you have Just My Code checked in Tools/Options/Debugging ?

Comment: hmm actually I had Common Language Runtime Exceptions (2 checkboxes), I have uncheked them and it appears problem is gone. Why is that? I like this more than fuslogvw approach. I understand an exception throw, I do not understand why test fails after that, I am guessing exception is still thrown, but since I am not breaking on it, I get different execution path?

Comment: I don't think the execution path is different. The exception breaks in the debugger. If you continue the execution, it should follow the same path.

Comment: oh well, the problem is, it doesn't follow the same path!

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues to be wary of.

1) As codeninja says, the order of operations may be different if you break the code.

2) Files may be in different locations, and paths may resolve differently. This is very important when you have dynamically loaded resources, or where DLL's are built and copied to a plug in's directory. Under debug you can accidently load the wrong one.

3) Observing variables in the debugger can cause an evaluation. Imagine a property which stupidly incremented its backing field and then returned the incremented value.

Comment: 1) No, if you aware of debugging muiltthreaded application, just break all other threads when debugging, so only one thread is debugged. That will be the same orded of operations, if you put a breakpoing in a source line after attaiching to running application.

Comment: 2) No, just turn debug option to find exact source match while debugging

Comment: 3) No, just turn off evaluation of prorperties & variables off, eliminating the side effects

Comment: 1) What? All that does is enforce the notion that code will execute in a different order. 2) Not the default and even if it were, you may not be debugging that code, perhaps just relying on a return value. 3) Again, not the default setting and if you do disable evaluation you disable a useful tool. As an example, my code would not cause evaluation side effects, so I'd leave it on because it is useful. Others' code may not be so well behaved. Final thought, all three points have caught out either myself or developers I've worked with. Thus I feel they are valid.